# Formatting Sharepoint columns with JSON

Tags: json, list, sharepoint, formatting

I am creating a Sharepoint list for a warehouse company I work for. The list contains all the aisles of the warehouse 1-94.

The aisles are split into different departments,

- Grocery (51-94), Frozen(1-16)
- Deli(17-23, 25, 36-39)
- Produce(24,26-34)

I need groceries aisle's to be one color, frozen to be a different color and so on. I have some code I found from here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

But, I can't figure out how to get the aisles 25 to be deli's color or 24 to be produce color because they don't fall into the >=, <= logic. Can someone implement OR == 25, OR == 24, or just a new scope for == 25, == 24?

```
{
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "@currentField",
"style": {
    "color": "#000000",
    "padding-left": "14px",
    "background-color": {
        "operator": "?",
        "operands": [
            {
                "operator": ">=",
                "operands": [
                    "@currentField",
                    51
                ]
            },
            "#e5e5e5",
            {
                "operator": "?",
                "operands": [
                    {
                        "operator": ">=",
                        "operands": [
                            "@currentField",
                            24
                        ]
                    },
                    "#91ff94",
                    {
                        "operator": "?",
                        "operands": [
                            {
                                "operator": ">=",
                                "operands": [
                                    "@currentField",
                                    17
                                ]
                            },
                            "#fbff93",
                            {
                                "operator": "?",
                                "operands": [
                                    {
                                        "operator": "<=",
                                        "operands": [
                                            "@currentField",
                                            16
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "#91d2ff",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            } ,
                            {
                                "operator": "?",
                                "operands": [
                                    {
                                        "operator": "==",
                                        "operands": [
                                            "@currentField",
                                            25
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "#91d2ff",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            } 
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

> Also, anyone know if I can change the Title of a the list to be a
>   number value instead of a line of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample multiple conditions for your reference.

```
    {
  "elmType":"div",
  "txtContent":"@currentField",
  "style":{
  "color": {
      "operator": "?",
      "operands": [
            {   
              "operator":"||",
              "operands":[
               { "operator": "&&", "operands":[
                    { "operator": ">=", "operands": ["@currentField", 17] },
                    { "operator": "<=", "operands": ["@currentField", 23] }
                    ] },
               { "operator": "&&", "operands":[
                    { "operator": ">=", "operands": ["@currentField", 36] },
                    { "operator": "<=", "operands": ["@currentField", 39] }
                    ] } 
              ]
         },
         "red",
         {
            "operator": "?",
            "operands": [
                    {
                        "operator": "==",
                        "operands": [
                            "@currentField",
                            25
                        ]
                    },
                "red",
                "blue"
            ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your data is structured, you can use "Choice" column types to assign metadata to each record. This will simplify your overall implementation.

Now, there is also a no-code solution for Choice, Date/Time, and Boolean column types that does not require knowledge of complex JSON to assign background colors.

[No Code Column Formatting – SharePoint Online](https://www.technologytobusiness.com/microsoft-sharepoint/no-code-column-formatting-sharepoint-online)